# Storing key/value pairs globally in Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I need to access the NAME of the languages and their respective  ID from a global array. I have added PHP files under the config directory and added the following code. Is it the right way to do it? How can I access it in my controller file?

```
return [
    'Language' => [
        array( 
            "English" => array (
               "name" => 'English',
               "value" => 101
               
            ),
            "Turkish" => array (
               "name" => 'Turkish',
               "value" => 102
               
            ))
    ]
];
```

Comment: The Laravel documentation has a section on [Accessing Configuration Values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `config/language.php` with the contents

```php
///config/language.php

return [ 
    "English" => [
        "name" => 'English',
        "value" => 101
               
     ],
     "Turkish" => [
         "name" => 100,
         "value" => 101
               
     ]
];
```

Then anywhere your need you can access like

```php
$lang = config('language.Turkish');

$lang['name'] //will be 100
$lang['value'] //will be 101
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is it possible to loop through this array? @Donkarnash

Comment: Yes you can get the languages by doing config('language') it will return the array then you can perform normal array operations on it @logeeks